# Any working example of jQuery UI tabs with the validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, validation, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-tabs

Does anyone know if there's working example of the tabs with the validation plugin?

I've been reading the documentation for both but can't wrap my head around how to use them together.

Need to validate fields on every step when user click next button to go on next step.

Comment: My basic intention is to achieve following things:
1- Wizard Style
2- Single Form for whole wizard
3- I need tabs as well so user can switch back on any step
4- I need validation on each wizard step. 
If there is a plugin which can perform same thing will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want a wizard like interface. You should check out some other plugins/libraries that are designed for that purpose:

- [jQuery Formwizard Plugin](http://thecodemine.org/)
- [Smart Wizard 2.0](http://techlaboratory.net/labs/SmartWizard2/smartwizard2-validation.php)
- [jWizard](http://dominicbarnes.us/jWizard/)

The ones listed above all can validate the fields.

Comment: Thanks William, Actually I need tabs too. Above mentioned wizards do not have tabs exactly. I like the jQuery Formwizard but can you guide me to set tabs in it?

Comment: Smart Wizar is closest possible choice but I find out in their documentation : "Smart Wizard 2.0 does not have in-built form validation, but you can call you own validation function for each steps..." Can we use [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) with it. If yes... please guide how? Thanks in advance

Comment: The author recently published [Smart Wizard v3.0](https://github.com/mstratman/jQuery-Smart-Wizard). I haven't worked with both of them, but I believe you should be able to use validation's [`valid()`](http://rocketsquared.com/wiki/Plugins/Validation/valid) at Smart Wizard's `onLeaveStep` option.